# Xamarin Android: Creating an add user activity, how to display all the error message at once and disabling as and when user fills the form?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
var nametext = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.nametext);
var emailtext = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.emailtext);

Button nextButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.next);
nextButton.Click += delegate
{
    if (nametext.Text.Length < 1)
    {
        errorFlag = 0;
        nametext.SetError("Please Enter Name", errorIcon);
    }
    if (emailtext.Text.Length < 1)
    {
        errorFlag = 0;
        emailtext.SetError("Please Enter Email", errorIcon);
    }
    if (errorFlag == 1)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
        intent.PutExtra("name", nametext.Text);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

After this statement, I can validate one by one but not both at a time on click of submit button. Also should do the regular validation for the email id.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Krumelur:I want to show both fields as required with error message. Now i am able to show one by one.

Comment: If you call `SetError()` for two different input fields, both of them will indicate an error to the user.